# Border, that overlaps near cells

Tags: html, css

That's how cell selection looks in MS Excel:

[image]

Is it possible to have the similar border in regular HTML `<table>` so that the border overlaps near cells (if you look closely you'll see that the border is extended for about `1px` each side over near cells)?

Comment: As per answer by @jn_pdx, that seems to be the default behavior (at least in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: @bfavaretto: yep, seems so... Need to figure out now why it doesn't behave in that way in my layout (but it is another story))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to a certain extent.  I've only tested in Chrome, but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/q4Lcc/

```
td {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid gray;  
}

td#test_td {
     border: 3px solid black;   
}
```

Comment: Note that you have to add `table { border-collapse:collapse; }`, otherwise the table will have gaps between the cells.

Comment: Uhm, I cannot get now *why* it overlaps?!

Comment: @zerkms, it's probably a consequence of `display: table-cell` (as we know divs don't behave like that).

Comment: @Zeta, you seem to be right, and the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#collapsing-borders) for collapsing borders seem to be dictating that behavior (so I was wrong about `display: table-cell`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it purely with tables, but one approach would be to use another `div` or text input that gets absolutely positioned over the table of data.

Here's a live example: http://jsbin.com/edehoc

I personally like this approach because it lets you use a familiar form element that has an expected style when it gains focus.

Comment: Yep, that is the only thing I think of too, but I hope(d) there is less painful solution